# TypeError: undefined is not a function on a Form in a Partial with nested Controller

Tags: angularjs, forms, laravel-4, angularjs-scope, http-post

I'm trying to `POST` from an `AngularJS Form` to a `PHP emailing file`.

I've been struggling with this problem and I have tried almost everything related to `$scope` and `controllers` but with nothing useful at all, but what I ended up with after troubleshooting is that the second I remove the `<form>` html tag within my partial view, the error disappears, but also the `ng-submit` would not work since it is within the `<form>` tag.
I have 2 controllers for the same view, and tried to use only 1 controller but had the same error appear again and again with everything I tried, within the view, and within the controller, except for the `<form>` tag as I just said.

This is my controller code:

```js
<script>
        myApp.controller('FormController',
            function($scope, $http, $window) {
                $scope.CompanyEmail = $window.email;

                $scope.formData = {};

                $scope.processForm = function(formData) {
                    //console.log(formData);
                    $http({
                        method  : 'POST',
                        url     : { 'templateUrl' : 'angularjs-app/views/contact_us.php' },
                        data    : $.param($scope.formData),
                        headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
                    })
                    .success(function(data) {
                        //console.log(data);

                        if(!data.success) {
                            $scope.errorFirstName = data.errors.firstname;
                            $scope.errorLastName = data.errors.lastname;
                            $scope.errorPhone = data.errors.phone;
                            $scope.errorEmail = data.errors.c_email;
                            $scope.errorCompany = data.errors.company;
                            $scope.errorComment = data.errors.comment;
                        } else {
                            $scope.message = data.message;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        );
</script>
```

```html
<div ng-controller="contact_us">

    <h2 style="margin: 20px;">

        {{subject}}

    </h2>
    <p style="font-size: 15px; margin: 20px;" >

        {{body}}

    </p>

    <div id="contact" style="float: right; " ng-controller="FormController">
    <h2 style="margin-right: 30px"> TITLE </h2>
    <p id="article"> PARAGRAPH </p>

        <!-- SHOW ERROR/SUCCESS MESSAGES -->
        <div id="messages" ng-show="message">{{ message }}</div>

    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" name="form" accept-charset="UTF-8" ng-submit="processForm()" >

        <input type="hidden" name="CompanyEmail" ng-value="CompanyEmail"  />

        <div id="first-name-group" class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorFirstName }">
        <label> Name *<br> </label>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder=" "  required class="form-control" ng-model="formData.firstname">
            <span class="help-block" ng-show="errorFirstName">{{ errorFirstName }}</span>
        </div>

        <div id="last-name-group" class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorLastName }">
        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder=" "  required class="form-control" ng-model="formData.lastname"><br>
            <span class="help-block" ng-show="errorLastName">{{ errorLastName }}</span>
        </div>

        <label> Phone  </label><br>
        <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" maxlength="13" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.phone"><br>

        <div id="email-group" class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorEmail }">
        <label> Email  *</label><br>
        <input type="email" name="c_email" id="c_email" autocomplete="off" required class="form-control" ng-model="formData.c_email"><br>
            <span class="help-block" ng-show="errorEmail">{{ errorEmail }}</span>
        </div>

        <div id="company-group" class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorCompany }">
        <label> Company *</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="company" id="company" required class="form-control" ng-model="formData.company"><br>
            <span class="help-block" ng-show="errorCompany">{{ errorCompany }}</span>
        </div>

        <div id="comment-group" class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorComment }">
        <label> Comments *</label><br>
        <textarea name="comment" id="comment" required style="height: 200px; width: 350px;" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.comment"></textarea><br>
            <span class="help-block" ng-show="errorComment">{{ errorComment }}</span>

        
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">
            Submit
        </button>

    </form>

    </div>

</div>
```

Note:

1- `Scope variables` of the upper controller works fine. `{{subject}}` and `{{body}}`

2- I have Arabic all over the form, but I doubt that has anything to do with it.

3- `<input type="hidden" ng-value="CompanyEmail">` works fine when I comment out the `<form>` tag.

4- I'm using `Laravel` for my back-end, and the `AngularJS App` code is in the `home.php` file within the **Laravel Views** folder, and my **AngularJS Partials Views** are in the public folder.

> This is exactly my error:

TypeError: undefined is not a function

at toggleValidCss (localhost/money/public/scripts/angularjs/angular.js:16293:14)
    at new FormController (localhost/money/public/scripts/angularjs/angular.js:16288:3)
    at invoke (localhost/money/public/scripts/angularjs/angular.js:3965:17)
    at Object.instantiate (localhost/money/public/scripts/angularjs/angular.js:3976:23)
    at $get (http://localhost/money/public/scripts/angularjs/angular.js:7315:28)
    at http://localhost/money/public/scripts/angularjs/angular.js:6711:34
    at forEach (localhost/money/public/scripts/angularjs/angular.js:332:20)
    at nodeLinkFn (localhost/money/public/scripts/angularjs/angular.js:6698:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (localhost/money/public/scripts/angularjs/angular.js:6146:13)
    at nodeLinkFn (localhost/money/public/scripts/angularjs/angular.js:6746:24) angular.js:10126 (anonymous function)angular.js:7398 $getangular.js:6755 nodeLinkFnangular.js:6146 compositeLinkFnangular.js:6042 publicLinkFnangular.js:6166 $get.boundTranscludeFnangular.js:6773 controllersBoundTranscludeangular-route.js:865 vangular.js:13093 $get.Scope.$broadcastangular-route.js:547 (anonymous function)angular.js:11682 deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallbackangular.js:11682 deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallbackangular.js:11768 (anonymous function)angular.js:12811 $get.Scope.$evalangular.js:12623 $get.Scope.$digestangular.js:12915 $get.Scope.$applyangular.js:8450 doneangular.js:8664 completeRequestangular.js:8603 xhr.onreadystatechange

Comment: seems the `FormController` you posted is not complete. Where is the `toggleValidCss` function?

Comment: Why would I need one, plus this isn't probably the case... I'm new to **AngularJs** and I just did this after a tutorial on `scotch.io`, so it should probably work without the `toggleValidCss`, I guess. @DonJuwe

Comment: Well, the error says it does not find this function when it is trying to call it. This breaks your code.

Comment: There are all those under the `TypeError: ...` not just this one. @donJuwe